# Working out why a block of code gives a certain output

Tags: python, output

Consider the following function:

```
def fun(lst):
    for item in lst:
        cmp = 0
        for other in lst:
            if item < other: 
                cmp -= 1
            elif item > other:
                cmp += 1
         if not cmp:
            return item



nums = [1,3,2,2]
print("fun({0}) = {1}".format(nums,fun(nums)))
```

I know that the ouput of this code is:

fun([1, 3, 2, 2]) = 2

But I don't know why. Can someone explain why this is the output?

Does anyone have any tips on how to make interpreting a block of code easier...

As I won't obviously have access to python in my exam and I'm struggling to work out what some blocks of code actually do.

Thank you.

Comment: Try working the example out on paper (run through the code), and the actual function will become obvious

Comment: @Nirk, For some inputs it returns `None`. It's a bit of a mouthful trying to describe the conditions for returning `None`

Comment: @gnibbler got any way of briefly describing how this thing works? I just can't get my head around it...

Comment: @Emma this computes the median of the values.  If the list does not contain the median (e.g. [1,2,3,4]), return None.

Comment: @Emma, `if not cmp` obfuscates it's meaning. Replace it with `if cmp == 0`. Now look at the inner loop `for other in lst:` and work out the conditions that will lead to `cmp == 0`. ie. an equal number of `-=1` and `+=1`

Comment: @Nirk, I told you it'll be a mouthful.. `[1,2,2,2,3,3]` certainly does contain the median, but it still returns `None`

Comment: Thanks @gnibbler and Nirk, making more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's wrong alignment in your code ("if not cmp:" should be one position left,
and last two lines should be on the same column as the first line is) like this:

```
def fun(lst):
    for item in lst:
        cmp = 0
        for other in lst:
            if item < other: 
                cmp -= 1
            elif item > other:
                cmp += 1
        if not cmp:
            return item

nums = [1,3,2,2]
print("fun({0}) = {1}".format(nums,fun(nums)))
```

the fun function returns the first array's item such that "not cmp", that is cmp != 0.
cmp is a number of array elements which are less than the given item minus number of 
array elements which are more than the item

```
  if item < other:
    cmp -= 1
  elif item > other:
    cmp += 1
```

Now, lets look at array items [1, 3, 2, 2]

1: has 3 items more than self (3, 2, 2) and no less than self, so cmp = 0 - 3 = -3, no return

3: has 3 items no items less than self and three (3, 2, 2) more than self, so cmp = 3 - 0 
= 3, no return

2: has one item more than self (3) and one item less (1), cmp = 0, function returns it (2)

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone have any tips on how to make interpreting a block of code easier...

Write it out. Give each name its own space on the page and track changes to the values while running through the code. After some practice you'll be able to track the simple values easily, only needing to write out the non-scalar values.

Answer (score 1):

```
def fun(lst):
    for item in lst:
        cmp = 0
        for other in lst:
            if item < other: 
                cmp -= 1
            elif item > other:
                cmp += 1
         if not cmp:
            return item

nums = [1, 3, 2, 2]
```

Your code has a nested loop, a for-loop within a for-loop.

The outer for-loop is `for item in lst` and the inner for-loop is : `for other in lst:`

The loops look something like this:

```
1(outer) - > 1, 3, 2, 2   # 1,3,2,2 are assigned one by one to `other`
3(outer) - > 1, 3, 2, 2
2(outer) - > 1, 3, 2, 2
2(outer) - > 1, 3, 2, 2
```

It starts with the outer loop first, value assigned to item is `1`, and `cmp` is set to `0`.
Now it iterates over the whole list inside the inner loop.

The first value assigned to other is `1`. Now it checks whether it is greater than or less than `item`(1 in this case) and increments or decrements the value of `cmp` based on that.
In the next iteration other is now assigned `3`, which is again compared against item(`1`) and changes the value of `cmp` based on that. Similarly it moves to the the next two items `2`,`2`.

Now comes this condition:

```
if not cmp: return item
```

it checks whether the value of `cmp` is falsey or not, if `cmp` is 0(0 is falsey value) then  it returns the item and the function terminates. (`not 0` is `True` in python)

If the condition is false then it moves back to the outer loop, and this time `item` is assigned the value `3` and then the inner loop continues as already described above except the fact that `item` is now `3`.

What the inner loop actually does is it actually compares how many items are greater than or less than the current item.

```
1(outer) - > 1, 3, 2, 2   # cmp is -3, because 3,2,2 are bigger than 1
3(outer) - > 1, 3, 2, 2   # cmp is 3, because 1,2,2 are smaller than 3

2(outer) - > 1, 3, 2, 2   # cmp is 0, because 3 is greater than 2 and 1 is smaller
                          # than 2, so the condition `if cmp` is True for this case
                          # and the function  return 2 (i,e. item)

2(outer) - > 1, 3, 2, 2   # this is never reached as function already returned
```

In case all loops are over and for `cmp` never turned out to be 0 then your function will return None(default return value of a function).